# How can I test whether stdout matches a pattern, but still print it?

Tags: bash, pipe

I would like to do something like the log analyzer of the running process. Let's say I run a server, stdout passes through the pipe to the bash script, where is IF statement. IF the string "somethings" appears in the output, then the script kills the server. If not then it normally prints stdout and still is running.

Example:

```
./server | if.bash
```

The contents of if.bash:

```
if grep 'somethings'; then
     kill app
else
     echo server output
fi
```

The above code successfully runs the test, but doesn't print the original stdout. How can I ensure that content is still printed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'kills the server'?  If you mean that the bash script closes its end of the pipe so that the server will get a SIGPIPE when it writes data, then what you want is relatively easy.  If you want the script to do some introspection on the process group and figure out the pid of the server and send it a signal, that will be more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Read the output in a loop:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ something ]];
    then
        kill app
        break
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done
```

Another option is to use `tee` when running the script:

```
./server | tee /dev/tty | if.bash
```

`tee` will output the messages on the terminal and also send them to the pipe.